# PHP 7.0 GD troubleshooting

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, php-gd

I have trouble while installing PHP 7.0 GD library. All other modules work fine.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

It shows me the following errors.

```
php7.0-gd : Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.1) but 2.1.0-5+deb8u6 is to be installed
```

What should I do ?

Thanks!

Comment: Install the latest version of libgd3 first. Then you should be able to install PHP 7.0 GD.

Comment: I have removed and reinstalled but it keeps installing this version. What should I do ?

Comment: Not the greatest with linux, but isn't there a way to request a certain version via apt-get ?

Comment: I tried to specify the version but it failed to find the new version.

Comment: Sounds like the package hasn't been updated yet, which sucks. You can try sourcing it online perhaps?

Comment: I have updated it to latest version. Still getting same error. I guess the error says that whatever version of libgd I have, I must have "2.1.0-5+deb8u6 is to be installed" this version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Raspberry and I solved it using the jessie backport:

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install libgd3
```

then I had the required version of libdg3 and I could install php7.0-gd without problems.